# How to retrieve range of data in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have user's data which have uuid as their key. I want to send mail to each user, But I don't want to send them mail all together so I want to retrieve range of user.

For example, I have 1000 user's now I want to send mail to range 1-100 user then 101-200 , 201-300 and so on. How can I achieve this? 
I have seen `startAt()` and `endAt()` functions, but my question is I don't know user key at the beginning and at the end. So I won't be able to retrieve range from that way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the first 100 users you'd do a query on:

```
query = ref.orderByKey().limitToFirst(100)
```

Then as you process the users, keep track of the last key you've processed:

```
vast lastSeenKey;
query.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
    lastSeenKey = userSnapshot.key;
  });
});
```

And then to load the next 100 users, you make the query start at the last key you've seen:

```
query = ref.orderByKey().startAt(lastSeenKey).limitToFirst(101)
```

You'll note that we retrieve one extra item here, since the first user in this query will be the same as the last user in the previous query.

Comment: Thanks Frank van Puffelen

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen How do I achieve inverse of this? I want to fetch latest first. (which is last entered data I fetch first). then get older 10 records then again oldest 10, ....